# How to search only by username with YouTube API?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube API to return the details of videos belonging to selected/ specific content creators - the problem is that the search below returns any video in which the listed username appears (anywhere) even if the username appears in the comments.

So in short, trying to make the search more restrictive/ specific.

Here's what I've currently got:

```
channels = ['elrubiusOMG','VEGETTA777','WillyRex']

yt = YouTubeDataAPI(api_key)

def getVideos(channel):
   return yt.search(channel, max_results=50)

for channel in channels:
   channelVideos += getVideos(channel)
```

Comment: I have never used the api but having a quick look at the documentation have you tried using `return yt.search(channel_id=channel, max_results=50)`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle - did the trick. I had been looking at the problem for too long and obviously missing the obvious!